# I don't understand how sets can be closed, yet disjoint?

Tags: general-topology

What are some closed, disjoint subsets $A, B$ in $R^2$ where $inf\{d(A, B) = 0 \forall a \in A \forall b \in B\}$?

Comment: How about the graph of the equation $xy=1$ and the x-axis?

Comment: Did you try and search the site before posting the question?

Comment: @OldJohn is it closed by ($0, \infty$)? That's open. Please clarify why that works.

Comment: @DonLarynx The x-axis is the set $(-\infty, \infty)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and this is clearly closed.

Comment: @OldJohn if it was closed why isn't it denoted by $[\infty, \infty]$?

Comment: @DonLarynx because $\infty$ does not belong to $\mathbb{R}$. It only belongs to the set of extended real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, $A=\{(x,y)\mid xy=1,x>0\}$ and $B=\{(x,y)\mid xy=-1,x<0\}$